# Meteor Blaze mixins not registering

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm creating some custom Blaze components inside a package and I've distilled some shared functionality into a mixin. However, for some reason my mixin is not recognised and I see errors like this:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: Must be attached
    at DOMRange.firstNode (domrange.js:191)
    at Template.constructView.view.templateInstance (template.js:168)
    at templateInstanceToComponent (lib.coffee:12)
    at lib.coffee:104
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:560)
    at Object.Blaze._getTemplateHelper (lib.coffee:103)
    at Blaze.View.lookup (lookup.js:104)
    at template.nav.js?4fba4334a27ad5d54a92350b0b1bb6bbd979ceb3:21
    at null.<anonymous> (builtins.js:49)
    at view.js:191
```

This is what I have:

In `mixins.js`:

```
var InputMixin = BlazeComponent.extendComponent({
  foo: function() {
    // A helper
  }
});
```

In `input.js`:

```
var InputComponent = BlazeComponent.extendComponent({
  mixins: function() {
    return [InputMixin];
  }
}).register('InputComponent');
```

And in my `packages.js`:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.addFiles([
    'lib/client/mixins.js',
    'lib/client/input.js',
  );
});
```

Not sure how to approach this issue. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code? Are you sure you are using the latest version of Blaze Components?